# Relation between $v$ and column space of matrix $A=(I+vv^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the identity matrix with a symmetric rank-one update, i.e., $A=I+vv^T$. Is there any relation between $v$ and the column space of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is positive definite (Hint: all the eigenvalues are $\geq1)$, therefore it has full rank and so the column space is the whole space.

Comment: The kernel of $vv^T$ is the subspace orthogonal to $v$, which has dimension $n-1$. The only dimension remaining is the space spanned by $v$, which is an eigenspace of $vv^T$ with eigenvalue $v^Tv$ (since $\left(vv^T\right)v=v\left(v^Tv\right)$). Therefore, $vv^T\sim  \mathrm{diag}\left[v^Tv,0,0,\ldots,0\right]$, and then $I+vv^T\sim \mathrm{diag}\left[1+v^Tv,1,1,\ldots,1\right]$